# Auto shrink title in product archive?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

I'm using Elementor with JetWooBuilder from Crocoblock. When designing the product archive page I would like all rows to be equal height. When the product tile is too long it needs two lines, and making that product "card" bigger than the one with one title line.
Is there any way of auto shrinking the title to make it always fit in one line?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that the cards have not the same height in your shop page. To fix it, add the products grid in your shop page and toggle "Equal Columns Height" in the product grid settings.